# Python 2.7.2 and Google App Engine SDK 1.6.1 on Win 7 Home Premium not working

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

I have installed Python 2.7.2 (Win7 32-bit) and Google App Engine SDK 1.6.1 for Win7 on a 64-bit system running Win7 Home Premium.  Default folder locations for both Python and GAE.  When I try to run the *helloworld* project as described in the Google Python Getting Started doc, the Launcher's "browse" button never becomes active.  The GAE SDK is supposed to do fine with Python 2.7.

Is there a complete listing anywhere of environment variables needed for this setup to work?  So far, all posts I have seen are from users who have gotten well past this absolutely basic step.

Comment: You can try run your project from the command line and see if that if preferable to you. I use the command line instead of the launcher on Windows 7 with python 2.7 and I don't use the launcher because I get more control from the common line: `python dev_appserver.py project_name`

Answer (score 3):

The Google docs for setting up GAE with Python 2.7 have some issues. If you are trying to launch the basic "hello world" app through the GUI App Engine interface, after following the instructions, you are probably seeing red text and all the buttons are grayed out?

If so, it is because there are errors within your helloworld.py program - this is where the Google instructions failed.

The import statement they have in the instructions:

```
import webapp2
```

This fails, it needs to point to the local instance of GAE's webapp. Also, their Python 2.7 program is incomplete. If you look at the Python 2.5 example, you will see the complete program (you may need to modify webapp --> webapp2 for Python 2.7?):

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Last thing, the YAML file in the Google instructions refer to "helloworld.app" - I can't confirm this, but I think it needs to be "helloworld.py" ?? I don't know, I may be wrong.

A couple months have gone by since you posted the question, if you found out any details, please feel free to update this question.

Comment: Actually, Google's Python program works correctly.  It turns out the `def main()` line, `if __name__` line, and `from` lines you've written are _not_ necessary for webapp2 in Python 2.7.  Those were for the older webapp (not webapp2) library ([source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#wsgi)).  You can verify this by pressing the run button on Google's [hello world tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld), which will take you to the appengine where the tutorial is functioning correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, browse button was disabled. I ran dev_appserver.py helloworld command at command prompt and then opened localhost:8080 in my browser the hello world program ran successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I compared the helloworld example to the guestbook demo and found that the application element was key.  I added the line at the top of the app.yaml file "application: helloworld" and the helloworld example started working in the Google App Engine (GAE).  Note that the 'application' element is supposed to be optional as defined in the app.yaml reference.  It looks like it is optional if you use the command line, and it is not optional if you use GAE.

Comment: it helped but, at first this header was causing problem during deployment. So I removed application header and through gcloud clone the project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything in the GAE SDK logs?

Which browser are you using? What is your default browser?

The default security settings in IE require you to enable intranet access.

I recently had to rebuild my Win7 dev box. Chrome was my default browser. When I installed GAE SDK v1.6.1 I had a similar problem to what you describe.

I checked logs and fiddled with the browser configuration to resolve it.

My recollection was that once I made IE 9 my default browser again, i saw the intranet security error. After enabling access to intranet sites like localhost:8080, things started working OK, but start-up was sometimes slow. Then I made Chrome my default browser again and the start-up became a bit faster and more reliable.

Comment: By "GAE SDK" logs, do you mean the logs for the launcher? How do I get those? I see an "SDK Console" option in the menu but it's permanently disabled (GAE 1.7.5 on Win7).

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that is because you had changed the encode from ANSI to another type (such as UTF-8) on app.yaml,

change it back to ANSI, then you can run the project on google app engine launcher.

BTW, the helloworld tutorial on google has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; it turned out my problem was *not* due to environment variables.

**Debugging GAE:**

First off let me say that if you are having problems with GAE, I would *strongly* recommend launching using the CLI, `google_appengine/dev_appserver.py`.  There is a large stack trace of the reason GAE is failing (instead of simply a red link in the GAE Launcher GUI) that will point you in the right direction.

**Hidden bad characters:**

When copying the text from google's "hello world" tutorial, there was an invisible hidden character at the start of my YAML file (I found it using kdiff, a diff tool).  After deleting this character, my app launched (and showed up as not red in the GAE Launcher GUI).

**Environment Variables:**

As to your original question, the only relevant environment variable I have set is my PATH variable, where I have appended the folder of my python executable (in my case C:\Python27) so that I can run python files without specifying the full path to Python.  Let me repeat, however, that I do not believe this is the cause of your problem, but you can more directly confirm this using the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Like [pghprogrammer4 above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632351/2821447), I solved this problem by removing bad characters in my files. They were invisible in my regular text editor (sublime text 2) but I found them with that editor's hex editor. I knew what to look for, because I noticed a space at the start of my Guestbook app (a few tutorials in). So I looked at the debug in Chrome, and it showed the character [Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). The Unicode site has the hexadecimal value of this character so I searched for that (didn't need to search far; it was the first three bytes of the file), and removed it. Thankfully Sublime Text 2 has a hexadecimal mode, but you could use any hex editor to find and remove the bad characters.

I am certain that this is due to a very particular method of copying and pasting from the Google tutorial site. It didn't happen to me in the Hello World example because I typed that out by hand. Then it appeared in one of my files, causing the CSS not to load. After that it caused the Google App Engine Launcher to think of my project as having missing files (turning up red in the launcher). I reverted to a working version (just by undoing in the text editor), and copied each set of new commands into the file from the tutorial, hoping to catch the bit of script that was doing me over. But when I got to the end it was all working. I SURMISE that this error is introduced when you copy and paste AN ENTIRE box of text from the Google App Engine tutorial site and insert it into one of your files. I suspect that ZWSP character exists on that site as the first character in the code boxes or something, but it's late and I'm not going to look into it further for now.

I guess you should just type out the tutorials - it's probably a better way to learn anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did two changes together -
1. added the line at the top of app.yaml file "application:helloworld"
2. changed the last line in app.yaml "script: helloworld.app" to "script: helloworld.py"

my GAE started working. However to islolate the issue I 'undid' both changes, it turns out that the the 2nd change - changing helloworld.app to helloworld.py did the magic